# Charset issue: external javascript file drops non-ASCII characters in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

Javascript strings with non-ASCII characters work as expected successfully when placed inside a  tag in the HTML file, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('tänään');
</script>
```

That is, an alert window pops up with the word 'tänään'.

However, if the code linked externally in a javascript file, e.g.

```
<script src='js/alert.js'  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the 'ä' characters are replaced with null-glyph characters ('t�n��n').  Using the charset attribute does not fix it:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="js/alert.js"></script>
```

Why is this happening?  What fixes are available?

Comment: The way I solved it is by converting all my js and html files to utf-8. I find it a better practice for multi-language sites.

Comment: `js/alert.js` has to actually be utf-8 encoded, setting a charset attribute will not change the encoding to utf-8.

Comment: @Gil, submit this as an answer and I'll accept it. Kind of a 'duh' moment for me :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding a charset indicator for the browser, like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

All text based files (html, js, and oh what the heck css) should be converted to utf-8 as well.

Keep in mind to convert the files to `UTF-8 without BOM` to avoid those annoying empty lines that will appear on some browsers.